# Prove this formula follows from a function being continuously differentiable?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm studying for an exam in an electrical engineering course (stochastic process in dynamic systems), though this section is strictly on the math. A given practice problem (with no solution given, of course) is:

"Show that if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable around $x_0$, then $$f(x) = f(x_0) + A(x-x_0)+g(x)$$ where $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{||g(x)||}{||x-x_0||}=0$$

Note that in the first equation, A is the matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ at $x_0$

The approach I've taken, which I don't think is correct, is as follows:

$f$ is continuously differentiable, then $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-A\dot(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||}=0$$

So we have $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-A\dot(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||} = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{||g(x)||}{||x-x_0||}=0$$

$$\frac{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)-f(x_0)-A\dot(x-x_0)}{\lim_{x\to x_0}||x-x_0||} = \frac{\lim_{x\to x_0} ||g(x)||}{\lim_{x\to x_0} ||x-x_0||}$$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)-f(x_0)-A\dot(x-x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} ||g(x)||$$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x_0)+A\dot(x-x_0)+||g(x)||$$

Since the codomain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$, we can assume the codomain of $g(x)$ is also $\mathbb{R}$, meaning $||g(x)|| = \sqrt{g(x)^2} = g(x)$, which leaves us with

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x_0)+A\dot(x-x_0)+g(x)$$

Here, I'm tempted to just drop the limits, leaving the equation which was to be shown. But I feel like this is wrong, because it seems strange to equate two functions because their limits are the same. For example, if $r(x)=x$ and $s(x)=\sin(x)$, $$\lim_{x\to 0}r(x) = 0 = \lim_{x\to 0}s(x)$$

But certainly $x\neq \sin(x)$

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: $g(x)=sin(x)$ does not fulfill $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{||g(x)||}{||x-0||}=0$

Comment: Your argument is completely faulty. You have zeros in the denominator at many places.

Comment: I think the hint that will help you solve this is that if $f$ is continuously differentiable, then $A=df$ is continuous.

Comment: Looks like just an unpacking of the definition of derivative.

Comment: B.swan: sorry for the confusing notation. I was just providing an example of a case where two functions whose limits are equal are not themselves equal. g(x)=sin(x) is a separate function, not meant to satisfy the actual problem given.

Comment: Could you expand on your suggestion? I know that f being C1 implies A is continuous, but am not sure where to go from there. Kavi: where are there zeros in the denominator? $x-x_0$ is not zero except where $x=x_0$, which doesn't actually occur as we are taking limits. And Matematleta, could you be more specific?